# Uncaught (in promise) undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, google-chrome, promise

I am getting the following error in chrome, and have no idea where it is coming from:
[image: Error]

The only thing that is really telling about anything is that I recently refactored about 10,000 lines of code and this error appeared some time in the middle of that. This is angular. I know how to catch promises, in angular. I am using an error handler to try and catch it but that did not work I also tried:

```
window.addEventListener('unhandledrejection', function (promiseRejectionEvent) {
  console.log(promiseRejectionEvent);
  console.log('here!!!!!')
});
window.onerror = function (promiseRejectionEvent) {
  console.log(promiseRejectionEvent);
  console.log('AHHHH')
};
```

Neither one of those caught the error. I have no idea where this error is coming from. It will appear every time I reload the page.

For the truly curious I have tried going to the link in chrome and it points to ... so not really helpful.

This error does not happen in firefox.

Comment: I am sorry but nobody is going to be able to help you here. There is just not enough information.

Comment: I didn't really think anyone would be able to tell me how to debug this... but I am hopeful enough to post this here so that a future person getting this odd error will see he is not alone in his sorrow.

Comment: Hint: Your error is in the first line of code in `cell-dial`. I would also question why someone who doesn't know angular is put in charge in refactoring 10,000 lines of code.

Comment: .....really....?? I know angular. I built most of those 10,000 lines. The error is DEFINITELY not in the first line of cell-dial. That points to my index.html document.

Comment: I guess you built your application in prod mode. Try to build it with the sourceMap flag setted to true and try to debug the code from the inspector.

Comment: I have sourceMap flag set to true. That screenshot is from the chrome inspector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running your code in Incognito.

I found the answer and it was less than satisfactory. It was a Microsoft Office extension that was somehow injecting something that was getting half caught by zone.js, but kinda not. I have NO idea how that happened.

Finding the bug:

If you make chrome pause on exceptions then it WILL stop on this error. The error was in a content.js file which is not in my project so I said "hmm...". I then went to the location of the file by right clicking in the sources tab, and found that the error was in the Office extension. So if you get this `Uncaught (in promise) undefined` it is because somehow zone.js error handling is catching it. I have NO idea how, but try running your code in Incognito.

Answer (score 7):

The message `Uncaught (in promise)` is part of zone.js:

https://github.com/angular/zone.js/blob/master/lib/common/promise.ts#L194

Using chrome dev tools, either search all files (cmd/ctrl+shift+f) for this text or jump  (cmd/ctrl + p) to zone.js and find 'Uncaught'. Put a breakpoint, reload page and inspect callstack once your breakpoint is hit.

Hope that'll point you in the right direction.

Comment: Although not really correct, I gave you the points because it pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: thanks @SamuelThompson, hope you found the problem - anything worth sharing?

Comment: Same here, knowing this message come from zone.js helped me a lot! Upgrading zone.js solve my issue. Thanks @corolla

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you that there is an error but you don´t catch it. Most probably you can check the responsible router for the route `/app/outbound/cell-dial` or any route guard function that relates to that.

For more information routing, but especially about router guards: https://angular.io/guide/router

Other options would be:

- Reinstall your dependencies with

```
// Delete
rm -rf node_modules/
npm install
```

- Check your repo diff from your last commit/merge/pull step by step
- Check your versions, because there is a possibility that you have different dependency versions than before that wasn't setup properly.

In general this is how you can catch it (that you probably already know, but I still mention it just in case):

```
getAllPosts().then(response => {
    console.log(response);
}).catch(e => {
    console.log(e);
});
```

More information: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch

Or with async/await:

```
//some async function
try {
    let response = await getAllPosts();
} catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As other responses suggest, try adding a breakpoint to where the stacktrace from the console points to. Then go up the call stack, and you probably find where a Promise is rejected in your code.

On my side, it was because we used `Promise.reject()` in a function without wrapping the call within a `try/catch` block. It worked fine until we added `await` to the function call, which triggered the unhandled promise exception and bubbled up to `zone.js`.